# Format of value in ComboBox is not showing correctly

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I have a ComboBox with a list of times on it, the ComboBox obtains the values from a sheet in the workbook and uses RowSource to put them on the ComboBox. (These cells are formatted as hh:mm)

[image]

Originally the ComboBox would display the values in the correct format but then when selecting one of these values it would show the selected time as a number rather than a time

For Example, 9:00 would show as 9:00 on the list of times but when selected would convert it to 0.375

[image]

To solve this issue I used the following code

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()

ComboBox5.Value = VBA.Format$(ComboBox5.Value, "hh:mm")

End Sub
```

So now 9:00 is shown this way

[image]

This works perfectly for all of the times that I have on my list except for 12:00, when I select 12:00 it shows an error of

[image]

Does anybody know why this is only giving me an error when I select 12:00 as the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, please the next approach. It adds a small value (equivalent of a second), in case of `0.5`...

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = Format(IIf(Me.ComboBox5.Value = "0.5", _
               "0.500011574074074", Me.ComboBox5.Value), "hh:mm")
End Sub
```

If you still have a problem, this can only be the result of the second time `Change` event being triggered by event itself code.

Since `Application.EnableEvents = False` does not work for form controls, we must build our own way of making the event to be triggered only once:

1. Create a `Private` variable on top of the form module:

```
    Private NoEvents As Boolean
```

2. Adapt the `Change` event in the next way:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
        If Not NoEvents Then
            NoEvents = True
            Me.ComboBox5.Value = Format(IIf(Me.ComboBox5.Value = "0.5", _
                      "0.500011574074074", Me.ComboBox5.Value), "hh:mm")
        End If
    End Sub
```

3. Make the boolean variable false in an event being triggered after the `Change` one:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox5_Click()
        NoEvents = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: the first version worked perfectly without no problems! thanks!

Comment: @sam0406: I asked because in my installation (Excel 2016 Pro Plus) your code did not return any error. It only returned 00:00 Instead of 12:00. I firstly did the trick involving a second time value adding, but I started thinking that maybe your problem has another root. Nevermind, glad I could help you...

Comment: no idea why it was giving me that problem (I'm also using Excel 2016), I remember it was also giving me that error when having "6:00" as my time but then I removed it as It was not working hours and did not need it on my list but for some reason it did not like either 6:00 or 12:00 but your trick worked so its fine now